# Retrieving values from two columns based on different conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a question for you all. I have 'inherited' a DB at work and I have to create a report from a table using different conditions. Please note I'm no sql expert, I hope what I write makes sense.

Trying to simplify, I have a HARDWARE table that contains the following:

- **HWTYPE** - *type of hardware*
- **HWMODEL** - *model of hardware*
- **PHONENUM** - *phone number*
- **USERID** - *user the hardware is assigned to*

the data looks like this:

```
HWTYPE | HWMODEL    |  PHONENUM  |  USERID
-------+------------+------------+----------
SIM    |  SIMVOICE  |   123456   |   CIRO

SIM    |  SIMVOICE  |   124578   |   LEO

PHONE  |  APPLE     |            |   CIRO

PHONE  |  SAMSUNG   |            |   LEO
```

now as you can see, every user has assigned one phone and one SIM with a phone number.

I need to sort the data per user, so that every line of the query result look like:

```
HW       |   PHONENUM   |  USERID
---------+--------------+------
APPLE    |   123456     |  CIRO

SAMSUNG  |   124578     |   LEO
```

so basically: group column PHONENUM and HWMODEL based on USER.

And this is where I get stuck! I tried union, join, case etc. but I still don't get the correct result.
Again apologies for the (probably) very basic question. I tried to look for something similar but could not find anything.

Thanks to whoever will want to help me.
regards
Leo

Comment: For some reasons I cannot edit my post to add 'hello SQL Experts' at the beginning.

Comment: `SELECT (HWTYPE, HWMODEL, USERID) FROM HARDWARE GROUP BY (USERID)` should do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also get your expected Result using below query. This will use self join on Hardware table as well as reduce the length of query syntex.

```
SELECT H2.HWMODEL AS HW,H1.PHONENUM,H1.USERID FROM HARDWARE H1 INNER JOIN HARDWARE H2 ON H1.USERID = H2.USERID
    WHERE ISNULL(H1.PHONENUM,'') <> ''
    AND ISNULL(H2.PHONENUM,'') = ''
ORDER BY H2.HWMODEL ASC
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know that I understood your question or not 
But i think you just need to write following query for your O/P

```
SELECT 
  HWTYPE, HWMODEL, USERID 
FROM 
  HARDWARE 
GROUP BY  USERID ,HWTYPE,HWMODEL
ORDER BY  HWTYPE
```

Comment: hello, thanks, but if I do this SQL Server return an error because HWMODEL and HWTYPE are not contained in GROUP BY clause, and if I add them I simply don't group anything...

Comment: @Leo ooooopps I forgot to write HWTYPE & HWMODEL in the group clause

Comment: Sorry but this query will not return expected result as you require phone number in your result.

Answer (score 1):

Placing my comment as an answer;

Write this as your SQL:

```
SELECT 
(HWTYPE, HWMODEL, USERID) 
FROM 
HARDWARE 
GROUP BY (USERID) /*Other Clauses can be added here, but ensure you use commas to seperate them!*/
```

Taking this step by step:

```
SELECT ... -> what columns you want to see
FROM ... -> what table you want it from (use joins if you need from multiple tables)
GROUP BY... -> What you want to collect together
```

There is also:

```
WHERE... -> conditions for when to include/what not to include
```

Comment: No Problem! However I would advise learning SQL from the likes of [w3 schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/)

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is a list of Phone numbers and models sorted by user, you can use this query:

```
SELECT HWMODEL,PHONENUM,USERID FROM HARDWARE ORDER BY USER
```

Hope to have understood your question

Comment: thanks for your reply, but in this case I get only the lines ordered by user: in my table, every user appears in two rows: one with phone number, one with device. I need to group them in one single row, so I see with a glance what user has what phone and what phone number. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    hw.HWMODEL as HW
    ,phone.PHONENUM
    ,user.USERID
FROM
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            USERID
        FROM
            HARDWARE
    ) as user

    LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            USERID
            ,PHONENUM
        FROM
            HARDWARE
        WHERE
            PHONENUM IS NOT NULL
    ) as phone
      ON phone.USERID = user.USERID

    LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            USERID
            ,HWMODEL
        FROM
            HARDWARE
        WHERE
            HWTYPE = 'PHONE'
    ) AS hw
      ON hw.USERID  = user.USERID
ORDER BY
    user.USERID
    ,hw.HWMODEL
```

Comment: This is absolutely brilliant and completely out of my league. Thanks!

Comment: I clicked on the 'accept as answer' arrow; it tells me I have to have 15 rep points to vote but the arrow stays green. Hope you get this as vote. thanks!

Comment: @iValueValue, why are you doing multiple left joins? Not only would it be bad practise to be doing this on a single table, but also highly inefficient!

Comment: The bad practice is the data model not the query. The distinct users are selected first as there was no requirement listed by the OP that a phone *must* have a sim card associated with it, or vice versa. Therefore, you first need a list of distinct users, and given there is no guarantee that there will be *both* a phone and a simcard for *every* user, left joins are required. If the data most certainly does have the restrictions in place then the query can be re-written, however given the general requirements, a general query was produced that would suit the need whatever the case.

Comment: Doesn't the line *every user has assigned one phone and one SIM with a phone number* tell you there **is** a Sim with a phone with a number (via the use of EVERY). However, there may be a time when there isn't a phone number/sim associated, but this would just show up as null, and no error ***should*** occur.

Comment: "Please note I'm no sql expert" + "now as you can see, every user has assigned one phone and one SIM with a phone number." could mean *his* representation of the table only, and not necessarily the table itself, so I've provided something that works. I didn't believe an explicit statement was made, hence the generality of the query. Given you've raised the issue of my interpretation of the OPS requirements, I'll leave it to you to write your efficient version you feel should be used instead.